# Toggle switch without clicking List Item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I currently have a list with a bunch of list items in them, and each list item has text and an on/off switch button, the problem i'm having is that when the switch button is clicked, it also clicks the entire row or list item as well, I want to click the switch button without it clicking the entire row with it.

I added a codeSandBox link with the code to make it easier:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-32j3b?file=/demo.js

Comment: a simple hack is to disable the ripple effect on ListItem. here is the example => https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hwi1u

Comment: That doesn't work for me caus I want to be able to click the list separate as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 things to notice here

- First, to use `Switch` without affecting the click behavior of `ListItem`, you should use `ListItemSecondaryAction` ([official doc demo here](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#checkbox))
- Second thing, as you know, to use `react-window` properly, we could not ignore `style` (cited in [doc](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window#why-is-my-list-blank-when-i-scroll)), but when using `style` directly with `ListItem`, combining with `ListItemSecondaryAction`, it could result in the break in stylesheet. So to avoid that, leave `ListItem` stay clean without any style overriden, by wrapping it arround a container (I use `Box`) with that `style`
- Finally, when using `ListItemSecondaryAction` as last child, `ListItem` ([doc](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/)) will use an additional container component for that, and default is `li` tag, so to avoid this, override by setting `ContainerComponent` prop to `div`

```js
function renderRow(props) {
  const { index, style } = props;

  return (
    <Box style={style}>
      <ListItem button key={index} ContainerComponent="div">
        <ListItemText primary={`Item ${index + 1}`} />
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
          <Switch
            defaultChecked
            color="default"
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "checkbox with default color" }}
          />
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
    </Box>
  );
```

Below is the forked codesandbox for solution demo

[image: Edit Material solution]

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the bubbling of the click event from `Switch` via `stopPropagation` so that the parents' `click` events do not get triggered when you click `Switch`.

As for the ripple effect, this is produced by the `button` prop that you have passed to the `ListItem`. If you with to disable that as well when `Switch` is clicked, you can set `disableRipple` to true on the `ListItem` when `Switch` is clicked.

```
const [disabledRipple, setDisabledRipple] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setDisabledRipple(false);
}, [disabledRipple]); /* re-enable it afterwards */

<ListItem button style={style} key={index} disableRipple={disabledRipple}>
    <ListItemText primary={`Item ${index + 1}`} />
        <Switch
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            setDisabledRipple(true);
          }}
        />
        ...
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-t6lqh?file=/demo.js

n.b., capitilize `renderRow` to transform it into a React function component

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@material-ui/list-item-secondary-action](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-secondary-action/#listitemsecondaryaction-api). As an example see the **comment button** in this https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#checkbox